# Terminal output scrolling is gone (Headless 11.10 Server, Upgraded from 10.10)

Tags: 11.10, command-line, mouse-scroll, scrollbar

I recently upgraded a 10.10 server (headless, EC2) to 11.04 and then to 11.10. Both upgrades seem to have worked, but now my terminal acts differently, particularly concerning output scrolling. I am accessing this server via Terminal on a 11.10 Desktop (GNOME fallback).

10.10 Behavior:

- A scroll bar is displayed on the right side of my Terminal, allowing me to scroll back to older output
- Turning the mouse wheel scrolls back to older output

11.10 Behavior:

- No scroll bar is visible
- Turning the mouse wheel cycles the current line through my command history (same as UP key)

This is a difficult issue to describe succinctly and I've had no luck finding any information about this. But I've performed the same upgrade several times (10.10->11.10) and the result is always the same concerning Terminal scrolling. Output scrolling is very important to me and something I take for granted - I'm concerned I'll be unable to work effectively on this server until I resolve this.

**Update - Problem magically gone after logout/login**
Well, as I said I've done the same upgrade several times and encountered the same problem. However, in the previous tries I was scared away and gave up. This time I was more determined to finish the upgrade and by simply logging out and back in to the server via SSH the problem has corrected itself.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The behaviour you describe sounds like your terminal was stuck in the full screen "cursor addressing" mode used by tools like `less` and `vi`.

The mode can become stuck if those programs do not exit cleanly.  For instance, if you `kill -9` them, or are running them through an `ssh` session that disconnects.  You can exit this terminal mode by running the following command:

```
tput rmcup
```

Or just try browsing a file with `less` and quit as normal.  You should then have access to your scrollback and the contents of the screen when cursor addressing mode was entered.

Comment: `tput rmcup` didn't make any visible change, but `tput reset` did the trick.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04 this problem occurs for me if an SSH session within the Terminal is broken. Just viewing a file with `less` and quitting works perfectly - easier to remember than the `tput` commands.

Comment: Looks like `tput reset` did the trick for me.

Comment: another possible culprit for this effect is [imwheel](http://askubuntu.com/a/304653/479118) running (not a default in Ubuntu 16.04, but readily available)

Comment: Neither the `less` trick nor `tput` is not working for me on 14.04.

Comment: `less` trick worked for me

Comment: same issue for me and tput rmcup worked.

Comment: starting and quitting `less` worked, but now my entire scrollback is gone (what was displayed before and what I wanted more of). Thanks for nothing.

Comment: `reset` will not get any of the output back, `rmcup` does. So I prefer it anyday as long as it does the work.

Answer (score 21):

If `tput rmcup` does not work, try

```
tput reset
```

instead.

Answer (score 5):

Just `reset` alone worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me on linux alpine