# Mouse Wheel Speed Problem

Tags: mouse-wheel

When the mouse wheel scrolls up or down very fastly, I can fix this problem by using "Pointing devices" software which takes part in Ubuntu Software Center. But this problem sometimes can again occur after fixing. I mean this solution is not permanent solution. It can want me an intervention to fix again. Is there any **permanent** solution to solve mouse wheel speed problem?

Comment: check this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed

Comment: Your question is answered here.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed