# 15.10 Mouse Scroll Speed - MX Master

Tags: 15.10, mouse, cinnamon, mouse-scroll

I'm new to Linux, running 15.10 with Cinnamon, and would like to be able to change my mouse scroll wheel speed. In Windows I can set how many lines I would like to scroll, but I can't find out how to do this on Linux.

I have an MX Master mouse, and I've installed Solaar,but all that allows me to do is pair/unpair, I can't edit any of the settings in the mouse.

So is there anyway I can do what I want?

Thanks in advance.

-G

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? Does this bump the post, if so is that allowed? :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed