# Can I increase the scrolling speed of Google Chrome without using any extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, mouse-scroll

There are several extensions for increasing the scrolling speed of Google Chrome such as SmoothScroll, Chromium Wheel Smooth Scroller and Gestures for Google Chrome™. But their performance does not meet my expectation.

When the mouse cursor points to some specific elements such as an adverting area like the following one, the fast scrolling seems disabled. It is a very bad user experience.

[Dead image was removed]

Is there a method for changing a variable in Google Chrome configuration page as if [what we do](https://www.maketecheasier.com/change-the-scrolling-speed-in-firefox/) to increase the scrolling speed in Mozilla Firefox in its `about:config` page?

How can I fix it?

Comment: To change it Ubuntu-wide, I use the "current way" from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/304653/479118). (Works with Ubuntu-Mate, too)