# Change scroll speed of external mouse only

Tags: usb, xorg, mouse, touchpad, logitech

My external mouse scrolls very slow (it's a MX Anywhere 2) but the scrolling of my internal touchpad is absolutely fine (for me). Therefore I want to change the scroll speed of my external mouse only which means that `imwheel` is not an alternative for me. I looked a bit further and found the following post ([Increase mouse wheel scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285689/increase-mouse-wheel-scroll-speed/639662)) with the following solution

> libinput seems to be included with Wily Werewolf (15.10) where you
>   need to install the package xserver-xorg-input-libinput. After you
>   installed libinput with
>
> $ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-libinput it should be used
>   for every input after you restarted the Xorg (logout would be
>   sufficient). Now that you are using libinput you are able to adjust
>   the settings of your mouse. You can find a full tutorial in the file
>   /lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-mouse.hwdb. Let me cover here only the basics.
>
> The following steps are need to be done as root. Because of that I am
>   friendliy reminding you that everything you do you need to take
>   responibility.
>
> First get the vendor id  and the product id  using lsusb.
>   Here with a MX 518 Logitech Mouse as example. If you have the
>   following line in the output of lsusb.
>
> Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c051 Logitech, Inc. G3 (MX518) Optical
>   Mouse The  is 046d and the  is c051.
>
> Then create a File that looks like the following with gksudo gedit
>   /etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-mouse-local.hwdb
>
> mouse:usb:vp:name:*:
>       MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE=?? For example this file for the Logitech MX 518 example above:
>
> mouse:usb:v046dpc051:name:*:
>       MOUSE_WHEEL_CLICK_ANGLE=30 This file sets the mouse wheel click angle to 30° (default is usually 15). To use this setting, update the
>   hwdb with the following commands:
>
> udevadm hwdb --update udevadm trigger /dev/input/event${id} One can
>   figure out the ${id} using xinput (look out for the id of your mouse)
>   and then run xinput list-props ${xinput_id}.

For some reason that does not affect my scrolling at all.
Does anybody have an idea how to fix it?