# Wheel scrolling with imwheel inconsistent

Tags: xubuntu, scrolling, mouse-scroll, mouse-wheel

Xubuntu 20.04 guest running in VirtualBox on top of Windows 10

Wheel scrolling was too slow, so I installed `imwheel` as recommended on [Increase mouse wheel scroll speed](https://askubuntu.com/q/285689/1175065) (and similar resources) and entered the following in `~/.imwheelrc` (to only change the behaviour in VSCode and Firefox):

```
"^Navigator$"
    None,      Up,   Button4, 4
    None,      Down, Button5, 4
    Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
    Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
    Shift_R,   Up,   Shift_R|Button4
    Shift_R,   Down, Shift_r|Button5
    Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
    Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
    Control_R, Up,   Control_R|Button4
    Control_R, Down, Control_R|Button5

"^code$"
    None,      Up,   Button4, 4
    None,      Down, Button5, 4
    Shift_L,   Up,   Shift_L|Button4
    Shift_L,   Down, Shift_L|Button5
    Shift_R,   Up,   Shift_R|Button4
    Shift_R,   Down, Shift_r|Button5
    Control_L, Up,   Control_L|Button4
    Control_L, Down, Control_L|Button5
    Control_R, Up,   Control_R|Button4
    Control_R, Down, Control_R|Button5
```

Unfortunately, it made the scrolling very inconsistent.  One wheel "tick" will scroll the screen a certain number of lines and the next will scroll by a different amount.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Sadly that's just how it is. It's had this problem for years...frankly I don't know if it's ever not behaved like this. On top of being inconsistent it's also jittery as h311 making what it does scroll jumpy and hard to follow visually to track if you've gone too far or not far enough. Sorry it's not an answer but given how long it's been like this I suspect it's not likely anyone will pop up with a "Oh just do X and Y and you're gold." reply. I'd have hoped this would be solved with libratbag or piper but so far it's not for my mice and my native drivers control all the fancy crap except scro