# Can't I scroll in the terminal up? Terminal shows only 24 rows? The scrollbar on the right fills the entire vertical height of the window?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, openssh, nohup

Based on:
[Terminal output scrolling is gone (Headless 11.10 Server, Upgraded from 10.10)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123206/terminal-output-scrolling-is-gone-headless-11-10-server-upgraded-from-10-10)
and
https://superuser.com/questions/1331658/why-cant-i-scroll-in-the-terminal
and my own dire situation right now.

## What I did before the problem occurred?

I'm running this `tor` relay on a VPS, and I'm monitoring it using `nyx` tor monitor. I'm connecting to this VPS from my home based laptop, running Ubuntu 22.04, totally updated version.

For the first time I was trying the `nohup` command run against `nyx` tor monitor.
I just wanted `nyx` to survive terminal disconnect (from my local Ubuntu 22.04 laptop), and be able to close the laptop, turn it back on again, ssh into my `tor` and `nyx` running VPS and bring back `nyx` from the background, instead of turning it on after the VPS login.
I've run `nohup nyx &` and then my problems started.
I've got the `nohup` output:

```
rafal@debian:~$ nohup nyx &
[1] 4532
rafal@debian:~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

Why `ignoring input`??
I need to pass the `nyx` password. How am I to do this without the input or while input is ignored.
How am I supposed to check if `nyx` even launched without a password or not??
I've typed `fg` and now I can type the `nyx` password.
So I type the password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> but nothing happens. I can see no input.

When I use `jobs` command, I get no output in return.

## What's wrong?

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> writes `2~` on the command line instead of scrolling,
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> writes `A` on the command line instead of scrolling,
3. Terminal on my home laptop shows only 24 rows, no matter what command I'll throw at it:
   `history` shows only 24 rows;
   `cat -n /home/rafal/nohup.out`or another command with a long output,
   `px -aux` shows only 24 rows;

[image]

[image]

1. The scrollbar on the right fills the entire vertical height of the window, indicating that there's nothing to scroll back to, while there are actually hundreds of lines above;
2. Turning the mouse wheel cycles the current line through my command history (same as UP key) instead of scrolling.
3. Of course I have 10 000 lines set in my `gnome_terminal` settings.

## The question

Can you please tell me what exactly happened and what `ignoring input` means and why `nohup` ignores input by default??

```
rafal@debian:~$ nohup nyx &
[1] 4532
rafal@debian:~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out'
```

I'm not using `tmux`.

In order to reinitialize the terminal, I've used `reset` to fix this.
And it did fix terminal.
Now after I use `px -aux` command I get full window height of lines like so:

[image]

Can you please explain to me, what am I doing wrong with this `nohup nyx &` command, that it's not working the way I expect it to??

Comment: "... ignoring input ..." because the process running your command is detached from the current terminal and its STDIN is no more tied to this terminal so can't receive input from it anymore ... The output, however, is added by default to a file `nohup.out` in the current working directory and you should be able to read it as it's added with something like `tail -f nohup.out`

Comment: For reference, another possible cause of stuck/changed scrolling behaviour is the terminal getting stuck with the [alternate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/) [screen buffer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/550938/).  Some programs such as `vim` switch the terminal to use an alternate screen buffer, so that you get your original screen back when it exits — but if it aborts/crashes without restoring the original buffer, the terminal can behave strangely.  (One workaround is simply to start and then exit `vim`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just how `nohup` works. It is designed to run a process in the background, detached from your shell session and will not accept input and by default sends output to `nohup.out`.

However, you want to use it to run an interactive monitor, so `nohup` is the wrong tool for the job. Just use `tmux` or `screen` instead. Run `nyx` inide the tmux/screen session, and then you can close the terminal or your laptop, ssh back to your VPS, start tmux/screen again and you're right back where you started.

Answer (score 2):

This is an addition to @terdon's answer, not a replacement for that.

Most terminal emulators have a "normal screen" and an "alternate screen". The latter one doesn't have a scrollback buffer, and is typically used by fullscreen apps. Apparently `nyx` is also such an application that switches to the alternate screen, that's why you cannot scroll.

Several terminals, including GNOME Terminal that you're using, send the keycodes of `Shift`+`PageUp` and friends (the scrolling keycombos) to the running application if you're on the alternate screen.